# prevent jms serializer to deserialize some attributes

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

If I post/put this json to my api:

```
{ 
    user: { 
        id: 1,
        name: 'John', 
        title: 'CEO' 
    } 
}
```

and deserialising and saving it to database in my controller with this:

```
$user = $serializer->deserialize($data, User::class, 'json');

$entity = $em->merge($user);
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

It will override the current user if it exist and update both name and title. But what if I only want this route to have permission to update the name? Is there some way that I can prevent some attributes from being deserialised? Like the title in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In jms serializer you can use General Exclusion Strategies:

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;

/**
 * 
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User
{
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @Expose
     */
    protected $title;
}
```

You can see here for more information: https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: Is this example using the build in serializer instead of the jms serializer? Can those be combined? I am using jms serializer

Comment: Does the general exclusion strategies also affect when adding content? I thought that it did only exclude things when fetching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have something more modular than the exclusion policy you can use forms.

Create a form :

```
class UserPutType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');
    }
}
```

And then in your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(UserPutType::class, $user);
$form->submit($request->request->all());

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    return $user;
}

return $form;
```

---

Another method could be to use route parameters if you only have to change the name of the user. You can use a method like this :

```
private function putUserName(User $user, $name) {
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

    $user->setName($name);

    $entityManager->updateUser($user);

    ... //Return statement
}
```

It works great if you don't have a lot of specific route to do.